# Fetching Nft value from smart contract

Tags: blockchain, dapp-development, nft, smart-contract-wallets

So today I got an idea to develop an application where users can mortgage their NFTs in return for ethers with added interest. However, one problem I'm facing is of accessing the value of NFT via #smartcontracts. I googled this but was unable to find the resources.

Anyone who knows how to do this share it with me as well

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing the value of NFT" ? What value ?

Comment: value of the nft in which it is bought eth/weth

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a source of truth for the question "what is the value of NFT 'x'". You can always ask OpenSea what the last sales price they saw was but that's hardly the value of an NFT as a decent percentage of the NFT market is not on OpenSea's proprietary website.